# CouchDB Java client

Tags: java, couchdb

This wiki page, http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java, lists several CouchDB Java clients. I wonder if any of the clients mentioned is significantly more dominant/popular/better/supported than the others.

Comment: Updated link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) is pretty much the clear leader at the mo. I've certainly been very happy with it, and I've never seen anybody using anything else.

In addition, as a quick metric, Ektorp is clearly far more actively maintained than any of the others: currently the last commit on Ektorp was 5 *hours* ago, vs 4 years for CouchDB4j, a little over 1 year for jcouchdb and 2 years for jRelax.

Comment: The last commit to Ektorp was Nov 2017, which seems like a really long time since Aug 2019.

Comment: Does it execute Mango query?

Comment: Please, update this answer or check the one i'v written

Answer (score 1):

I tried CouchDB4j and it has only a few methods implemented. They are not so well documented and you might find the complete lack of code example implementations very frustrating as it happened to me.That is why I would not recommend it. To give you a feel about this API, I tried attaching a certain file to an already existing document from the database and it does not support this kind of process.

I will now give Ektorp a shot and will come back with an edit as I go along. Looking at the recent activity between these two it is a big difference: Ektorp has been last updated a month ago vs CouchDB4j having been updated 3 years ago at the moment when this comment was written. Hope this will help.

**EDIT**: Ektorp is definitely the way to go. It allows you to build your own kind of entry in the database, with as many and variate fields as you want. It also allows easy manipulation of attachments. For me, it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays the most well supported Java Client for CouchDB should be the official one from IBM [cloudant-java-sdk](https://github.com/IBM/cloudant-java-sdk) as it is their interest to maintain it. [Here you can find it on Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.cloud/cloudant-parent).

Answer (score 0):

[Lightcouch](https://github.com/lightcouch/LightCouch) seems to be most active nowadays. [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) is also still active, however.

Each has its own strengths, however, so I'd pick based on what level you want to be abstracted from CouchDB's HTTP API. Myself, I'd use Lightcouch.

Comment: Lightcouch doesn't look like it's been consistently active at all.

Comment: Fair enough, I must've been fooled by a few recent commits.